# Kafka is not working on Azure Web App Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, apache-zookeeper

We are trying to deploy Kafka on Azure Web App Service.
Constantly we are getting the following error:
**Container NN didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 2181, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.**
WEBSITES_PORT is set to be 2181, and also on Dockerfile we have exposed the same port.

Later, for start up command we have set to start zookeeper and it seems like it starts normal but suddenly starts to repeat this:  WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn).

In local everything works fine.

Comment: Zookeeper isn't an HTTP server. Unclear why you're trying to make something do "HTTP pings on port 2181". That being said, a "web app" isn't really ideal environment to run a persistent service like Zookeeper (or Kafka)

Comment: I'm removing the Kafka tag again because Kafka doesn't use port 2181, as listed in your error

Comment: Hi. Anyway I am trying to deploy Kafka. Kafka tag is important to reach Kafka experts.

Comment: Perhaps, but not if the error you're getting is unrelated to Kafka. If you want to "run Kafka as Docker in Azure", you should at least mention which Kafka Docker image(s) you are using. If you simply want to "run a Kafka broker in Azure", I would suggest [Event Hubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka) rather than Docker anyway